# Javascript - Error creating objects on the fly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simulate data to a function that would usually receive a JSON parsed data structure.  When running this I get an error `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object` here: `data.targets[i] = {`

What am I doing wrong?

```
function SendFakeTargets(maxTargets, interval) {
    var data = {};
    data.timestamp = +new Date;

    var time = data.timestamp * 0.0005;
    var x = Math.sin(time) * 192 + 256;
    var y = Math.cos(time * 0.9) * 192 + 256;

    console.log(x, y);

    for (var i = 0; i < maxTargets; i++) {
        console.log(i);

        data.targets[i] = { //error is here
            id: i,
            x: x + (i * 10),
            y: y + (i * 10)
        };
    }

    HandleTargetData(data);

    setTimeout("SendFakeTargets("+maxTargets+", "+interval+")", interval);
}
```

Comment: var data = {targets:[], timestamp:Number(new Date)};

Comment: please don't use a string as the callback parameter to `setTimeout` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should previously declare

```
data.targets = [];
```

before using `data.targets[i]` inside the loop, otherwise `data.targets` is `undefined`. In a shorter way you could write

```
var data = {
    timestamp : +new Date,
    targets   : []
};
```

---

And as a side note, never use strings in `setTimeout/Interval`. Do instead

```
 setTimeout(function() {
      SendFakeTargets(maxTargets, interval);
 }, interval);
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the reasoning behind using a function call as opposed to a string? Is it solely to avoid an `eval` or is there another reason?

Comment: yep, it is to mainly avoid an `eval` (and for better readability - especially of arguments - imho)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to initialize the targets array before using it, as it is undefined. You are defining data as

`var data = {}`

which is declaring it as an empty object, anything else that you're doing with it is added on the fly - arrays need to be initialized before you can call any index in them. I believe what you need to do is:

`var data = { targets: [] }`

Answer (score 0):

You never declared "data.targets" as a an object so javascript doesn't know how to assign anything to it.

At the top of your code just define "targets":

```
data.timestamp = +new Date;
data.targets = {} or [];
...
```